# IE Edge, overflow:auto (or any scrolling) makes input element of type 'file' unusable

Tags: input, scroll, microsoft-edge

We have an input tag as such:

```
<input type="file" id="upload-video-input-element" accept="video/mp4">
```

If its parent has overflow:auto, the input element takes about 20 times longer than it should to load a video to the browser.  A 1 meg file can take 15 seconds with it on.  Turn off scrolling and it is almost instantaneous, as expected.  This only happens in Edge.  IE11, Chrome, FF, and Safari do not exhibit this behavior.

But we need scrolling on the parent.  Has anyone seen this?  Why is it doing it, and is there a fix?  thanks!

Comment: Can you create a fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

We were reading the file with a file reader and setting src to that large amount of data.  All browsers were fine with that accept Edge under certain conditions. Now we set src to the an object url with URL.createObjectURL(myFile).  Later, if the user submits the form, we read in the data, because currently our backend wants the 64bit encoded data.